# File parsing Swiss knife

Tags: bash, parsing, format

I am comparing the txt output of different pieces of software. Each one has its own output format. It can be JSON, XML, CSV, but also Custom format.

I am looking for a tool/language able to define my regular expressions in order to automate file parsing producing my own output.

I guess than 10 years ago the answer was: just use perl.

Today I am doing this usign python scripts but I am wondering if there is something more specific for this task.

Other requirements will be to have something light, standalone, portable, easy to learn, easy to mantain.

Any suggestion? Thanks

**EDIT:**

As requested: I am including some of the file parsing I am talking about.

Source I

```
<Phase = "phase2 - Name of the phase"  duration = "0.080" />
<Phase = "phase3 - Name of the phase"  duration = "3.670" />
<Phase = "phase4 - Name of the phase"  duration = "0.010" />
<Phase = "phase5 - Name of the phase"  duration = "0.030" />
<Phase = "phase6 - Name of the phase"  duration = "0.000" />
```

Source II

```
Round=50 Res one=-119.053794 Res two=0.007623 Value 1=0.011147 Best Res one=-119.053794 Perc accuracy=0.000000 eta =0.100000  time=0.042774
Round=74 Res one=-121.077763 Res two=0.004456 Value 1=0.000000 Best Res one=-121.077763 Perc accuracy=0.112613 eta =0.100000  time=0.049079
Round=75 Res one=-121.077763 Res two=0.000000 Value 1=0.000000 Best Res one=-121.077763 Perc accuracy=0.369369 eta =0.100000  time=0.049541
```

I would like to produce CSV, for instance

Out 1

```
"phase2";"Name of the phase";0.080
"phase3";"Name of the phase";3.670
"phase4";"Name of the phase";0.010
"phase5";"Name of the phase";0.030
"phase6";"Name of the phase";0.000
```

Out 2

```
50;-119.053794;0.007623;0.011147;-119.053794;0.000000;0.100000;0.042774
74;-121.077763;0.004456;0.000000;-121.077763;0.112613;0.100000;0.049079
75;-121.077763;0.000000;0.000000;-121.077763;0.369369;0.100000;0.049541
```

Comment: Give us a minimal example to work with and how you would like to parse it

Comment: Your input is by no means clear. What is your input file that you want to convert to the above mentioned format?

Comment: My input is just the text files I attached, and I attached it to better explain the question. But in any case I am not trying to find something specific for my input. I can manage with python. I am asking if there is a generic tool to perform this task.

Comment: Your question is going to be voted off to be closed I guess. Your requirements are not clear by any means. Good luck

Comment: Honestly I do not understand what is unclear. The input files are the ones below "Source I" and "Source II", the output file I would like to produce is a CSV. And I am looking for a specific tool to do that.

Comment: In any case, thank you Inian for give it a try  at least;)

Comment: @mosh42. Because, when you mean _output file I would like to produce is a CSV._ , the term is too broad and gives to many ways to interpret it. If only you give an "exact" output for input in question., people can understand your intentions and try to provide the exact solution for it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133694/discussion-between-mosh442-and-inian).

Comment: looks good enough! will try and provide an attempt!

Comment: Are they actual `XML` files? If so can you provide the complete file from root? Because some tools like `xmlstarlet` (tailor made for them) need a properly formatted `XML` input

Comment: No, they are not. It is XML-like custom format.

Comment: @mosh442, since the format is custom, you need to write a script in a programming language of your taste. Perl is still the best text parsing tool, IMO.

Comment: sorry, by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an attempt in `Awk` *ONLY* because you have claimed the files not the actual `XML` tools, because there are dedicated parsing tools like `xmlstarlet` to achieve that.

`Awk` is a powerful tool which can be used for both the input examples,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{n=split($2,x," - "); for(i=1; i<=n; i++){ printf "\"%s\";",x[i]} printf "%s\n",$4}' file
"phase2";"Name of the phase";0.080
"phase3";"Name of the phase";3.670
"phase4";"Name of the phase";0.010
"phase5";"Name of the phase";0.030
"phase6";"Name of the phase";0.000
```

`Awk` parses the input lines one at a time, with a syntax `BEGIN{}{}END{}` clause, with `BEGIN` and `END` getting executed before and after the processing of the actual file respectively. There are a few [built-in special variables](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web), important of them are input and output field separator, `FS` and `OFS` respectively. The input lines are split by `FS` and the individual fields can be accessed from `$1`, `$2`..

For the solution in first example,

- The input field separator is set to double-quotes `"` to parse the strings within double-quotes for your case. Here `$2` contains the entire string `phase2 - Name of the phase` so to split them as separate we use [`GNU Awk` split function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) which returns the fields split by the de-limiter (`-`) into an array `x` and word count (`n`)
- Now printing the values found using the `printf` with format specifiers including a double-quote.

and for the second example,

```
awk -F'[^0-9.-]*' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if (length($i)){printf "%s;",$i}  printf "\n" }' file
50;-119.053794;0.007623;1;0.011147;-119.053794;0.000000;0.100000;0.042774;
74;-121.077763;0.004456;1;0.000000;-121.077763;0.112613;0.100000;0.049079;
75;-121.077763;0.000000;1;0.000000;-121.077763;0.369369;0.100000;0.049541;
```

This is a pretty straight-forward solution, the key is to set the input field separator to `[^0-9.-]*` i.e meaning split on non-occurrence of the characters included i.e. numbers from `0-9`, `.` and/or `-` . With that it is easy now to parse the line to get the individual fields in a loop till `NF`, which means the max number of fields in a line. The `length()` function is to ensure, no empty characters are included for printing.

If you find the solutions pretty complex, suggest reading [GAWK: Effective AWK Programming by Arnold D. Robbins](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) to get you started on the language.